# Specify destination location for copying msi packaged in Wix Burn

Tags: wix, burn

Is there any provision to copy the msi file (specified in 'Msipackage' element) to a custom location (eg: c:\myfolder) from where it would be invoked by wix burn bootstrapper?

thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Burn sets up the package cache with security permissions to prevent unelevated code from escalating its privileges.  Starting with WiX v3.9 the user can change the location of the package cache, but that applies to all bundles and doesn't allow specifying separate locations for packages.